# Images to Video converter in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp4, video-processing, video-encoding

I would like to convert multiple images(frames) to a video(MP4) in an android device. Also, I would like to convert video(MP4) into multiple images(for each frame). I have limited knowledge on FFMPEG, but installing FFMPEG in Android may consume more time. I Would like to ask experienced engineers to suggest a better strategy which can take less time to complete this task. Please point me to some open source code which I may modify to complete this task quickly.

Comment: Do you want to do it programatically or are you looking for a program that does that?

Comment: I want to do it programatically as I am looking forward to modify the code and test with different formats in the future. C++ or JAVA would be good for me.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert Image to YUV format using Image Decoder.

Then you can feed each YUV Image as a Video Input to Media Recorder Engine.

Go through the Media Recorder Source Code to get more info.